# Is it possible to compile to YUL?

Tags: solidity, compiler, yul

So the solidity compiler compiles solidity first to YUL and then to machine code. Is it possible to compile it just to YUL and look it over?

It would be really helpful to learn how YUL works.

Thanks.

Comment: See what is [Yul intermediate representation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/ir-breaking-changes.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can use the compiler option `solc --ir a.sol` to see the Yul output.